# Can't get rid of the fill at (n,n)

Tags: python, tkinter

Trying to build the Game of Life program piece by piece and I'm confused as to why no matter what configuration I run, the bottom right rectangle fill is always red. Additionally, it reads the configuration file, but change the fill of any of the squares indicated by the file.

Configurations are text files in the filing format:

rownumber colnumber

rownumber colnumber

rownumber colnumber

```
LIVE = 1
DEAD = 0

def board(canvas, width, height, n):
    for row in range(n+1):
        for col in range(n+1):
            canvas.create_rectangle(row*height/n,col*width/n,(row+1)*height/n,(col+1)*width/n,width=1,fill='black',outline='green')                      

n = int(raw_input("Enter the dimensions of the board: "))
width = n*25
height = n*25

from Tkinter import *
import math

window=Tk()
window.title('Game of Life')

canvas=Canvas(window,width=width,height=height,highlightthickness=0)
canvas.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=5)

board = [[DEAD for row in range(n)] for col in range(n)]

rlist = [[None for row in range(n)] for col in range(n)]

print rlist

for row in range(n):
    for col in range(n):      
        rlist[row][col] = canvas.create_rectangle(row*height/n,col*width/n,(row+1)*height/n,(col+1)*width/n,width=1,fill='black',outline='green') 


f = open('configuration.txt','r')
for line in f:
    parsed = line.split()
    if len(parsed)>1:
        i = int(parsed[0].strip())
        j = int(parsed[1].strip())
        board[row][col] = canvas.itemconfigure(rlist[row][col], fill='red')        

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry I can't yet just comment in your question, but anyway.

In the last forloop you set i and j, however you never use them, instead you use row and col.

Comment: Thank you! Commenting a simple observation such as this seems more appropriate.

Comment: If what you want to add answers the question, then it should be an answer. This solves OP's problem, so it's fine as an answer (though you've gained enough reputation to leave comments from *this question*!).

Comment: Thanks for the second pair of eyes!